# Django ContentFile() unexpected empty line (django.core.files.base)

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with the ContentFile function of django.core.files.base

I wrote a function that allows me to save text into an .md file

```
def save(title,content)
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

I am using a simple textarea in a form that submits the content to the route that will save it.
The problem is that after saving every new line is duplicated:

```
Hello
World
```

Becomes

```
Hello

World
```

And this happens all the time. If you have 2 empty lines you end up having 4 of them...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by changing the last line of the save_entry function to

```
default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content.encode('ascii')))
```

per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053205

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and here is my solution:

ContentFile uses StringIO if you provide content as a string or BytesIO if you provide content as ByteArray. I guessed it could be issue of StringIO class so I simply converted my content to byte array and passed fixed argument so ContentFile class initialized BytesIO as stream_class:

```
byte_list = []
a_byte_array =  bytearray(content,"utf-8")
    for byte in a_byte_array:
    binary = bin(byte)
    byte_list.append(binary)
save(query, a_byte_array)
```